# Как передать произвольные числа и знак действия (клиент-сервер)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

Написал простейшее клиент-серверное приложение и смог передать  1,2,+ и в результате получил 3. Но сделал это я весьма "костыльно" поэтому если я пытаюсь отправить 10,2,+ то получаю 120. Можно ли как-то исправить логику (не могу представить как от слова совсем :/) ?
server

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 9090)
print('starting up on {} port {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:

    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('connection from', client_address)

        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            print('received {!r}'.format(data))
            if data:
                print('sending data back to the client')
                input_data = (data.decode())
                expression = input_data[0] + input_data[2] + input_data[1]
                #^^^вот тут повис...не понимаю как сделать также для 
                #дву,трехзначных и далее по списку....
                result = eval(expression)
                connection.sendall(str(result).encode())
            else:
                print('no data from', client_address)
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

client

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))

a = input("a= ")
b = input("b= ")
do = input("+ - / *  ")

message = a + b + do
sock.send(message.encode())

data = sock.recv(1024)
res = data.decode()
print(res)

sock.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Если входные данные 10, 2, +, то на сервер вы отправляете `b'102+'`.

На сервере вы берете 0-й, 1-й, 2-й символы (3-й, который `'+'` - вы игнорируете), и склеиваете `'1' + '2' + '0'` (2-й символ вставляете между 0-м и 1-м символами), получается `'120'`, и как к нему `eval` ни применяй - все равно получится 120.

Нужно либо чтобы операнды были одинаковой ширины, тогда их можно будет отделять друг от друга по размеру, либо просто добавить разделитель (например, пробел), на сервере разбивать по пробелу, потом уже собирать в выражение:

```
# На клиенте
message = ' '.join((a, b, do))
sock.send(message.encode())

# На сервере
input_data = data.decode().split()
expression = input_data[0] + input_data[2] + input_data[1]
```